# Laravel Eloquent can relationship method return null instead of MorphMany relationship object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, nullable, table-relationships

My problem could be more philosophical than concrete.
I'm using Laravel 8, I have one **Trait** that is used by **several classes** and some of its methods perform **two different computation** by taking into account if object has or not a specific **morphMany relationship** (here called **entries**). This trait is almost implemented with the following code:

```
trait MyTrait {
  // Some methods...

  // Entries methods
  abstract public function hasEntries();
  abstract public function entries();

  // Here is a method that depends on entries
  public function computFunc() {
    return $this->hasEntries()
      ? $this->computWithEntries()
      : $this->computWithoutEntries();
  }

  private function computWithEntries() {
    // Perform computation with entries by using entries() relationship...
  }
  private function computWithoutEntries() {
    // Perform computation without entries...
  }

  // Some other methods...
}
```

Obviously, **classes that have entries** relationship also **implement some criteria** inside hasEntries() method to check if there are entries for the current object, as shown in this example:

```
class ModelA {
  use MyTrait;

  public function entries() {
    return $this->morphMany(Entry::class, 'owner');
  }
  public function hasEntries() {
    return $this->entries()->where([ /* Some condition */ ])->exists();
  }
}
```

Now, my question is: what should return entries() method for classes that don't have entries relationship, meaning that **is not possible/allowed** for entries table to have column *owner_type* equal to one of those classes.

Here's an instance of this case (ModelB can't own any entry):

```
class ModelB {
  use MyTrait;

  public function entries() {
    // Should return null?
    return null;
  }
  public function hasEntries() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

What value/object should return entries() method for objects of class ModelB? I'm quite sure that to return null instead of relationship object isn't the correct thing to do, am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters for your use case. As long as you're checking `hasEntries()` (boolean `true` or `false`, either via hard-coded value, or `$this->entries()->exists()`) before attempting to call `->entries()`, it shouldn't matter. One caveat is that `public function entries() { ... morphMany() }` (and other relationships) make both `->entries` (property) and `->entries()` (method) available on the Model, which would not be the case for `entries() { return null; }`, but again, it _shouldn't_ matter. Just my 2 cents on the matter.

Comment: @TimLewis I agree with you, at the very end, the returned value doesn't matter for models that don't have entries. This because entries relationship method isn't called for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may accomplish this with a different approach. Try with this:

1. Split your trait in 2 different traits (one to create the relationship and the other to check if has entries and compute the result).
2. Create an interface (contract) that contains the methods of the second trait (just to get sure those methods exists in the class) so you can specify if the value to return should be boolean.

With that, you wont have problem in the computing part of the code. Hope my answer helps.

Edit - Super quick example:

```
//EntriesRelationTrait.php
trait EntriesRelationTrait {
    public function entries() {
        return $this->morphMany(Entry::class, 'owner');
    }
}

//ComputeByEntriesTrait.php

trait ComputeByEntries {
    public function computFunc() {
        return $this->hasEntries()
          ? $this->computWithEntries()
          : $this->computWithoutEntries();
    }

    private function computWithEntries() {
      // Perform computation with entries by using entries() relationship...
    }
    private function computWithoutEntries() {
      // Perform computation without entries...
    }
}

//HasEntriesContract.php
interface HasEntriesContract
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasEntries(): bool; 
    //function type declaration available only after PHP 7.0

}

class ModelA implements HasEntriesContract {
    use EntriesRelationTrait;
    use ComputeByEntriesTrait;

    public function hasEntries(): bool {
        return $this->entries()->where([ /* Some condition */ ])->exists();
    }
}

class ModelB implements HasEntriesContract {
    use ComputeByEntriesTrait;

    public function hasEntries(): bool {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The contract ensures that the created function follows a standard, in this case, a boolean response from the `hasEntries` method.

Comment: It is not quite clear, could you write a super quick example code?

Comment: @ManuelGuzman yes, this seems to me a clean solution to my problem, thank you